# Replaying enemy movement after ending turn

Tags: civilization-5

Is there a way to replay enemy movement for last turn? It often happens that enemy moves all over map and when I end my turn I just can't see where all the enemy units went - it is pretty annoying.

Comment: or highlight it or something

Comment: im gonna say no, I have no proof but I have been playing Civ 5 since it came out and have never seen anything like it, mods or ingame. I would think it to easy if I wasn't surprised by my enemy on occasion anyways.

Comment: you don't have quick movement activated while playing do you, if so that might be a way to fix it?

Comment: @Paralytic No - I actually played last game without quick movement and still I would run in situations where I'm chasing enemy ship for example, and it just vanishes in fog of war - and then I would need to make a guess which way it went (the movement doesn't get shown during computer's turn because there are too many units).

Comment: @kape123 if it vanished into fog of war, that means it's gone out of your line of view and there's no way for you to know the movement.

Answer (score 1):

No, I'm pretty sure there is no way for you to replay an AI's move, Most of the time, if you can't see where the AI's Units moved is because they are out of your line of sight, or in the "Fog of War". Which hides all units from view. Another possibility is that your are playing with "Quick Movement" on, just simply turn this off when creating a new game under Advanced Options.

Comment: The asker says in the comments that they *don't* have quick moving activated.